# Why conduct experiment for load distribution within three triangulated structural frameworks when you can calculate theoretically

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

So we are doing this project on conducting an experiment to investigate the Statical Equilibrium of Plane Frameworks. Why do we need to conduct such experiments when we can easily calculate by hand and by pin-joint analysis.

Answer (score 7):

There are several general reasons for conducting practical  tests in addition to theoretical analysis.

- to verify that the theoretical approach and associated assumptions are valid. Pretty much all loading models involve  some simplifications and assumptions.
- for quality assurance :  practical tests can pick up manufacturing/material defects,  design errors and mis-communications  between the design and manufacture stages
- regulatory approval : slapping a load on a structure is a lot easier to implement than verifying calculations especially in non-standard cases.
- practical testing verifies the whole product which can actually be less trouble than documenting every single stage of design and production.

You don't say if this is an academic project, if so it may simple be a case that the course wants to teach/evaluate both theoretical and practical skills. A huge aspect of real world engineering is having a sense of how theoretical models relate to reality and understanding that all models contain assumptions which may not always be valid.

Answer (score 2):

To compare the theoretical and practical results, perhaps understand the differences and evaluate the sources of errors, maybe due to measurement for example.